# Add Emoticon at my Simplenews Newsletter's subject

Tags: 7, emails

I send newsletters from my Drupal 7 website using Simplenews. What I want is to add emoticons at the subject of the newsletter, like a Smiley or something like this.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking text-based emoticon (e.g. ":)", ":D") then the answer is yes. If you're talking Unicode emoji-character based emoticons (e.g. ) then the answer is *maybe*. While Drupal sends out UTF-8 encoded emails, support for *display* of the emoticons depends totally on recepient's email client so your results will vary.

Comment: Also some emoticons (utf8mb4) are only supported when using a database that supports them because the title and other content are stored in the database.

Comment: I will send test newsletters to different email clients and I will see if they show or not. And one last question, how can I add them to the title? I think that I can't use html at the title, when I create a new newsletter, is that correct?

Comment: Lookup an emoji character chart. You can copy and paste them from your browser.